# Kafka - can the consumer group ids be configured with spring-integration simple consumers?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to configure kafka consumer group-ids with spring-integration simple consumers - the message driven channel option?
If not, which would be the best alternative if one topic is needed to function both as queue (inside consumers of the same group id) and as a classical topic (between consumers with different group ids)